# Do the configurations done inside a docker container persist after creating an image out of it?

Tags: 18.04, docker, container

Good day, I have tested multiple containers and every works fine. now I wanted to transfer those dockers into another machine without further configurations. My first attempt is to create an image out of the containers and install those images to the new machine. My concern is that will the configurations stay within the image or do I still have to reconfigure after installing unto the new machine?

Comment: Yes, if you make an image your configuration stays - that's kind of the point of an image.

Comment: @ArturMeinild So after it is installed, it should be good to go?

Comment: Yes that would be the case.

Comment: Great, thank you for the clarification.

Comment: @ArturMeinild One more thing, do the env also persist? Like should I still indicate the env's when running the images?

Comment: Env can be defined in the image, but overridden by definition in the docker or docker-compose command when run.